# CTRL+] in Vim on Macbook

Tags: macos, vim, tags, keyboard

I have an annoying issue with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> key combination in Vim on my Macbook. I have a Scandinavian keyboard, so I do not have a <kbd>]</kbd> key.  Normally I make a ] character by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>. This is an issue when I use ctags for example, as there is no simple way to jump around in files. I tried to use `map <C-9> <C-]>` in my .vimrc, but this does not seem to work. I did get it to work with `<C-K>`, but I would much rather prefer `<C-9>` (or maybe `<D-9>` - that is: Apple command key+9). How can I fix this?

Comment: See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932702/how-do-i-type-ctrl-on-a-quertz-keyboard-in-order-to-jump-to-a-tag-with-vim

Answer (score 1):

Search google for an american qwerty keyboard diagram then compare it with your actual keyboard. The key located at the same spot on your keyboard will work.

On a french keyboard, <kbd>$</kbd> is at exactly the same place as <kbd>]</kbd> so I must type `<C-$>` instead of `<C-]>`.

In your case, it's probably <kbd>^¨~</kbd>

Comment: +1 I can confirm that this way works for a (german) QUERTZ keyboard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932702/how-do-i-type-ctrl-on-a-quertz-keyboard-in-order-to-jump-to-a-tag-with-vim

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
map <C-\> :exec("tag ".expand("<cword>"))<CR>
```

Of course, replace `<C-\>` with whatever combination you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Closest I've been able to get is with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Numpad 9</kbd>:

```
nnoremap <C-k9> i
```

From what I can tell the regular number keys are not available for mapping.

The function keys work just fine though, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F9</kbd>:

```
nnoremap <C-F9> i
```